# Windows command console to run powershell script(ps1)

Tags: powershell

I'd like to run .ps1 from a batch file.
I need to download an executable file which needs http request only on the website.

And my .ps1 code works in Windows Powershell ISE(not been elevated), but it's not when running from my batch file.

My batch and .ps1 file as below, can anyone help me?

Here is the batch file

```
echo test

powershell -noexit -file C:\Users\username\Desktop\tyty.ps1

pause
```

And here is the ps.1

```
$userAgent = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::InternetExplorer
$downloadUrl = ((Invoke-WebRequest –Uri "http://tax.nat.gov.tw/info_BLR_download.html?id=2").Links | Where-Object {$_.href -like “*BLR_*I.exe” -and $_.href -notlike “*BLRATH*” } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href)
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadUrl -OutFile "C:\Temp\BLR.exe" -UserAgent $userAgent
```

error

```
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]。 C:\Users\username\Desktop\tyty.ps1:1 字元:14
+ $userAgent = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::InternetExp ...
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...nds.PSUserAgent:TypeName) []，RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Comment: PowerShell doesn't recognize the class [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.psuseragent), so my guess is you're not running PowerShell v6. Please show the output of `$PSVersionTable` in a console where this is not working.

Comment: Here is the screencapture of my PS console [https://imgur.com/TERJ5Jv] So it won't work if my PS version is under 6?

Comment: It seems like work when run my ps script on my console. https://imgur.com/Ije4zgM

Comment: Maybe it requires Windows 10 or something. Not sure. You should be able to provide the user agent as a string, though: `$userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0)'`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It's working as your way~~ Amazing !!!

Answer (score 0):

To make a type available, if PowerShell does not load it already automatically, just add the corresponding module or assembly manually by using [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Import-Module) or [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type). In your case, you have to load an Assembly as can be derived from the docs ([`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.psuseragent)):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility
```